# WooCommerce - Get custom product attribute

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, product

I am trying to get a specific custom attribute in woocommerce.
I've read tons of threads on this site which offer about 3-5 methods how to do it.
After trying all, the only method that worked for me is to loop through all attributes - all others did not work.
I have a custom attribute named 'pdfs'

**The following tries did not work:**   ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13374883/woocommerce-getting-custom-attributes))

```
 $global product;
 $myPdf = array_shift( wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, 'pdfs', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) ) );

 $myPdf = $product->get_attribute( 'pdfs' );

 $myPdf = get_post_meta($product->id, 'pdfs', true);
```

**This is the only one that did work:**   ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35089718/showing-more-product-meta-info-on-woocommerce-product-page/35667417#35667417))

```
 $attributes = $product->get_attributes();
 foreach ( $attributes as $attribute ) {
    if (attribute_label( $attribute[ 'name' ] ) == "pdfs" ) {
        echo array_shift( wc_get_product_terms( $product->id,  $attribute[ 'name' ] ) );
    }
}
```

I would much rather be able to use one of the first options
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Update: Added compatibility for Woocommerce 3+

As attributes are always prepend with **`pa_`** in DB, for getting them with **`wc_get_product_terms()`** function, you will need to use **`pa_pdfs`** instead of **`pdfs`**, this way:

```
global $product;

$product_id = method_exists( $product, 'get_id' ) ? $product->get_id() : $product->id; // Added WC 3+ support

$myPdf = array_shift( wc_get_product_terms( $product_id, 'pa_pdfs', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) ) );
```

Reference: [How to get a products custom attributes from WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13374883/woocommerce-getting-custom-attributes/13454788#13454788)

Comment: I'm get --> Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference. Woocommerce version 3.2.6. Code ---> $date = array_shift( wc_get_product_terms( $product->get_id(), 'pa_date', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) ) ); What can be wrong? I can't solve it. I get 'Null' of gettype($date). Maybe I could get some help?

Comment: @Kristis Updated the answer Adding WC 3+ compatibility… try it again.

Comment: Thanks, but I get same notice and type 'Null'.
Just in case this is my full code http://collabedit.com/vejqr

Comment: @Kristis You should better ask a new complete and detailed question on StackOverFlow, as your case is something different.